# Python, fichero concsv

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

soy nuevo por aqui . necesito ayuda. haciendo unas tareas de Python, con los ficheros de CSV me he quedado estancado....no se si alguien me puede hechar una mano...

1. Tenemos 9 columnas, las 8 primeras contienen datos numéricos con los cuales podemos trabajar, crea una lista para cada una de estas columnas (mpg, cylinders, etc.). No es necesario crear lista para name
2. Recorre los datos del csv adecuadamente y almacena los datos de cada columna en cada una de las listas que has creado anteriormente.
3. Comprobar que se haya guardado en las listas la información correspondiente (con prints)

Comment: Bienvenido a SO es, debes leer [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio, tambien [ask] para aprender a formular buenas preguntas. Debes saber que aca en Stackoverflow **NO se hacen tareas**, y toda pregunta debe tener una demostracion de esfuerzo para resolver el problema, osea un [example].

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a [es.so], te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. ¿Qué has intentado hacer hasta el momento? Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios publiquen sus preguntas junto con lo que han intentado, de esa forma se demuestra que has hecho un esfuerzo por resolver tu pregunta/problema, de lo contrario probablemente la pregunta termine cerrada y/o votada negativamente. Lectura recomendada: [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)